# lm-sensor and cpu temperatures

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I am on ubuntu Precise Pangolin. The processor is Intel i3. a desktop.

I installed `lm-sensors` and below is the report `sensors` gave

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +30.0°C  (high = +89.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +33.0°C  (high = +89.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

w83627dhg-isa-0a10
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:        +0.93 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:          +0.75 V  (min =  +1.99 V, max =  +1.99 V)  ALARM
AVCC:         +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:        +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:          +1.30 V  (min =  +0.90 V, max =  +1.77 V)
in5:          +0.76 V  (min =  +1.15 V, max =  +0.90 V)  ALARM
in6:          +1.06 V  (min =  +0.94 V, max =  +2.03 V)
3VSB:         +3.36 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:         +3.36 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.30 V)  ALARM
fan1:           0 RPM  (min = 3515 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan2:           0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan3:           0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
fan5:           0 RPM  (min = 10546 RPM, div = 128)  ALARM
temp1:        +39.0°C  (high = -121.0°C, hyst =  +9.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = diode
temp2:        +39.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = diode
temp3:       +127.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
cpu0_vid:    +2.050 V
intrusion0:  OK

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +70.5°C
```

The fans sensors are detecting 0 RPM and some temperatures are out of range - the ALARMs above but i dont understand it very well. Can someone help out?

Comment: Please share more about your hardware (mainboard). The sensors in the CPU seem to be working well, yet the others seem not to give the correct values. Also please share the output of the command in Frantique's answer (long output, please post on pastebin or similar).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `lm-sensors` is getting wrong data. Try to run `sudo sensors-detect` first. Read carefully every output, on the last question:

```
Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)
```

type: `yes`+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then reboot. See if something changed.

Comment: no real change as far as i can make out

Comment: how does one post on pastebin?